# PHP conditional loop - string length

Tags: php, loops, conditional-statements, do-while

I am sorry if this is a very stupid question, or an obvious newbie mistake - but I as basic as this is , I hardly never used the do - while loop before (I know - I can not comprehend it myself ! How is it possible that I managed to avoid it all those years ??)

so : 
I want to select a number of words from the begining of a text paragraph.
I used the following code :

```
   $no_of_char = 70;
   $string = $content;

   $string = strip_tags(stripslashes($string)); // convert to plaintext
   $string = substr($string, 0, strpos(wordwrap($string, $no_of_char), "\n"));
```

Which Kind of works, but the problem is that sometimes it gives EMPTY results.
I would think that is because the paragraph contains spaces, empty lines , and / or carriage returns...
So I am trying to make a loop condition that will continue to try until the length of the string is at least X characters ..

```
   $no_of_char = 70;  // approximation - how many characters we want
   $string = $content;

do {
       $string = strip_tags(stripslashes($string)); // plaintext
       $string = substr($string, 0, strpos(wordwrap($string, $no_of_char), "\n")); // do not crop words
       } 
while (strlen($string) > 8); // this would be X - and I am guessing here is my problem
```

Well - obviously it does not work (otherwise this question would not be ) - and now it ALWAYS produces nothing .(empty string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [str_word_count](http://uk.php.net/str_word_count):

```
$words = str_word_count($string, 2);
```

> 2 - returns an associative array, where the key is the numeric
>   position of the word inside the string and the value is the actual
>   word itself

Then use [array_slice](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$total_words = 70;
$selected_words = array_slice($words, 0, $total_words);
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem you have is that the string has blank lines at the start. You can easily get rid of them with [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/ltrim). Then use your original code to get the first actual newline.

The reason your loop didn't work is because you told it to reject anything that was longer than 8 characters.